# calculating limit of a markov chain

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, limits, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I want to calculate the following limit

> $lim_{n \to \infty}\  A={\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 &0 & 0&0\\1-p & 0 & p & 0&0\\0 & 1-p & 0 & p&0\\0&0&1-p&0&p\\0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}}^n$
>   where we know $0<p<1$.

I put some numbers instead of $p$ and calculated the above matrix for large $n$ and I observed that the limit matrix will be in shape of following matrix for $a,b,c,d,e,f \neq 0$

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 &0 & 0&0\\a & 0 & 0 & 0&b\\c & 0 & 0 & 0&d\\e&0&0&0&f\\0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

but the point is that I need to know exactly what $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are (regards to $p$).

Moreover, I think adding it would be helpful that the matrix $A$ is actually a transition matrix of a markov chain so as you can see the summation of each row is $1$.

another valid question is what would happen to limit if $A$ was an $N\times N$ matrix instead of a $5 \times 5$ one?

Comment: Consider diagonalizing $A$. Two of the eigenvectors will correspond to the eigenvalue $1$, the others will correspond to smaller eigenvalues. You can tell that the left eigenvectors are concentrated at state 1 and state 5, which gives your result (the other three rows will be some linear combination of those two). As for finding them, the total probability formula gives you a system of equations: for instance $a=(1-p) \cdot 1 + p \cdot c$, $c=(1-p)\cdot a + p \cdot e$, etc. You get six linear equations in six unknowns.

Comment: To be more explicit: $a=(1-p) \cdot 1 + p \cdot c,c=(1-p) \cdot a + p \cdot e,e=(1-p)\cdot c+p \cdot 1,b=(1-p) \cdot 0 + p \cdot d,d=(1-p) \cdot b + p \cdot f,f=(1-p) \cdot d + p \cdot 1$

Comment: This is a version of the Gambler’s Ruin problem in disguise.

Answer (score 1):

We see from the transition matrix $A$ that the Markov chain has two absorbing states—the first and last—while the rest are transient, i.e., the system eventually enters either the first or last state and stays there. As $n$ gets large, $A^n$ will approach a matrix $P$ of the shape that you’ve described. Each entry $p_{ij}$ of the non-zero columns is the probabilities of eventually reaching state $j$ if the system starts in state $i$.

To compute these probabilities, proceed as per @Ian’s comment. Each of the two non-zero columns will be a (right) eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$, that is, each will satisfy $(A-I)\mathbf v=0$. In this case, you only need to solve one such system of linear equations since we also have $p_{i5}=1-p_{i1}$.

As for the general $n\times n$ case, the result is similar: a matrix with only the first and last column non-zero, and the entries in those columns the probabilities of eventually reaching the corresponding absorbing state. To compute those probabilities, find a recurrence for the entries in one of the non-zero columns (the last one is the easier of the two to work with).